# How to select parallel lines in postgis

Tags: postgis, select, parallel-lines

I have roads`(MultiLineString)`table in postgresql database. The roads are classified based on priority attribute i.e.

```
  priority = 6 for motorway
  priority = 5 for highway
  priority = 4 for expressway
  priority = 3 for major road
  priority = 2 for minor road
  priority = 1 for street
```

i need to select all roads that are parallel to motorways`(priority = 6)`and are within 50 meters distance from either side. 
[image]

From the above image, i want to select the green color roads which are parallel to blue color roads.

**Update:**
i tried using buffer but this also returns the line which is not parallel to the blue line. As shown in the image below, the lines perpendicular to blue lines are also selected as a result.

[image]

Comment: I would try by creating buffers for the blue lines and selecting lines which are completely within the buffered geometries. With suitable buffer distance selection should contain the green lines and not too much other features.

Comment: creating buffers couldn't do it, as said in my updated question

Comment: If blue lines are not cut at intersections they are not completely within the buffered area. And by removing lines which intersect with the dark blue lines you can get rid of the thin blue ones.

Answer (score 6):

It would look something like this.

```
SELECT l1.geom, l2.geom AS non_intersecting_line
FROM lines AS l1
JOIN lines AS l2
  ON (
    ST_Intersects( ST_Buffer(l1.geom, 50), l2.geom )
    AND NOT ST_Intersects(l1.geom, l2.geom)
  )
WHERE l1.priority = 6;
```

**WARNING**: This doesn't strictly find parallel "lines." PostGIS is real world and not an abstract modeling tool. It doesn't have a notion of `y=mx+b` to constitute "parallel". This finds linesegments that do not intersect within 50 meters. They can be visually perpendicular non-intersecting lines in the United States and Zimbabwe, and this query will return them.

If you need [visually parallel line segments defined by two points](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_Azimuth.html)

- Calculate the azimuth of the desired line defined by two points.
- Calculate the azimuth of the line for comparison.
- Permit a margin of error for rounding points.

This still won't find lines *near* each other, but they should be parallel. For instance, lines of longitude are parallel with other lines of longitude but they can cross earth as separate points on the geode.

If you need visually parallel lines defined by more than two points: tough. You can either calculate the angle with *any* two points or you're not talking about a line anyway.

## Update with [sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxJDgNJFVXPxRVBULXBnYUJKT28/view?usp=sharing)

This is *exactly* the problem with your description..

- Green is the buffer zone 50 meters.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE service_rds_buffer AS
  SELECT gid, name, priority, ST_Buffer(geom, 50)
  FROM service_rds WHERE priority = 6;
  ```
- The two lines inside the green are the only two roads where `priority=6`
- That road curves. It's not a *line*. It's a *line segment* that represents a road composed of 121 discrete points. What does it mean to be parallel to a line segment like that? It means nothing. Which takes you back to my original query.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Instead of using ST_Intersects in inner SQL, how about using http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Covers.html for selecting only roads which are totally inside the buffered road? Perhaps it would help in finding visually parallel lines? Perhaps enhanced with ST_Distance and setting a minimum distance between l1 and l2?

Comment: Thank you @Evan, i tried the above query and i used `st_contains` instead of `st_intersects`. it seems like `NOT ST_INTERSECTS` does not work properly because the query still return the lines which intersect with blue lines.

Comment: Are you confusing `ST_Intersects` with `ST_Intersection`? ST_Intersects returns True-False? So long as they Intersect, they'll return `true`. We negate that so we only pull in the lines that do **not** intersect.

Comment: yes, i am aware of the `st_intersects` response. if i am right, the query should not return those lines which intersect with blue lines?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: here is the link for sample data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxJDgNJFVXPxRVBULXBnYUJKT28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: question updated.

Comment: Thank you @Evan for your help, parallel in this sense means that road with `priority = 6`  do not intersects with green road and are almost at the same distance. i think offset will be appropriate word for this.

Comment: I gave you the query for roads that *not not intersect* and the caveat for that. Good luck! I'm unsure of how to help you out any further because I don't know what offset means in this context, or how I go above and beyond "does not intersect" to satisfy whatever needs your application may have.